# show all tags excluding release candidates with git ls-remote

Tags: git

I currently have a deployment process where production release tags are in the form `v1.0.1` and stage/ release candidates follow the form `v1.0.1-rc.1`.  I see that I can use the below to pull in only release candidates:

```
git ls-remote --tags --refs --sort tag origin "refs/tags/v*.*.*-rc.*"

ba2ed... refs/tags/v1.0.1-rc.1
f37ac... refs/tags/v1.0.1-rc.2
```

But how can I do the opposite where I only see tags like v1.0.1, v1.0.2, etc where I might exclude tags containing the `-rc.` pattern?

Comment: You could append to you command ` | grep -v '-rc'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`grep -v`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to exclude (filter out) lines of output:

```
git ls-remote --tags --refs --sort tag origin "refs/tags/v*" | grep -v -e "-rc\.[0-9]\+$"
```

The regular expression `-rc\.[0-9]\+$` means:

```
-rc — literally
\. — literal dot
[0-9]\+ — any number of digits
$ — end of the string to avoid matching "-rc.1" in the middle
```

Comment: since the pattern `"-rc\.[0-9]\+$"` starts with a dash, you need to prefix it with `-e` : `grep -v -e "-rc\.[0-9]\+$"`

Comment: @LeGEC Good catch!

Comment: @phd: What if I just want to get heads?

Comment: @Paul https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote#Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt--h

Comment: Eventually I did it with a `--h --sort origin "refs/heads/*"`

Comment: If you have time you could take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884757/bash-git-ls-remote-remove-the-hash-via-regular-expression