# Bash git ls-remote remove the hash via regular expression

Tags: linux, bash, git, replace, grep

I have the following command which allows me to get a list like the one below:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/CodeEditApp/CodeEdit --h --sort origin "refs/heads/*"
```

```
...
45955931b326913390596b1970ebeb928ccc741e    refs/heads/add-docs-video
4d872980b6a606b9d40c9c3afa5987bbac701fc2    refs/heads/animation-test
c3969f86ea8e332c5b7e63ea8d246d5e7917d475    refs/heads/apple
....
```

the result I would like to get in the end would be just the branch names:

```
...
add-docs-video
animation-test
apple
....
```

Comment: Maybe something like `git ls-remote --heads origin | cut -f2 | cut -c12-`?

Comment: I did it this way, it seems to work, but what if there was something simpler:
`git ls-remote http://www.github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia --h --sort origin "refs/heads/*" | sed -r 's/^[a-z0-9]+//g' | sed -r 's/     refs\/heads\///g'`

Comment: You don't need it to be that complex... First, your `sed` assumes that hashes may contain lowercase letters beyond `f` (which is not true for hex16-encoded hashes in git output). Second, the ls-remote output is tabular already, so you can process it row by row and field by field: take the second field from each row (the first `cut`) and trim off the first 11 characters (the second cut tells "substring from character no. 12 inclusively"). No need to use regexes here either.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you give an example so I can prove it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk and grab the last field using `/` as a separator and then print the rest of the line from the 3rd field using the substring function like so:

```
yourcommand | awk -F/ '{print substr($0, index($0,$3))}'
```

Comment: It seems to work, the problem if I have a branch named `release/0.22.2`, what it returns to me is `0.22.2`

Comment: It provides false results for refs^W branches that use slashes in their names.

Comment: How about this command? `awk -F/ '{print substr($0, index($0,$3))}'`

Comment: Despite it seems to work better (perfect?) now, I would accept it as a "it just works" solution, however I think it's still a dirty (a premise for `/` as the major delimiter) and cryptic to some extent way (for those who don't use `awk`).

Answer (score 2):

As [terrorrussia-keeps-killing noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884757/bash-git-ls-remote-remove-the-hash-via-regular-expression#comment127027879_71884757), the output from `git ls-remote` is well-formatted.  I'd personally use:

```
git ls-remote ... 'refs/heads/*' | sed "s,.*${TAB}refs/heads/,,"
```

for this case, with `$TAB` set to a tab character (and re-insert desired URL and options into the `git ls-remote` of course):

```
TAB=$'\t'
```

You can use a literal tab character rather than expanding the variable `${TAB}`, or you can use the `$'...'` syntax in the sed command itself:

```
... | sed $'s,.*\trefs/heads/,,
```

but I like to use named variables (`$TAB`, `$NL`, etc.) to hold my white-space characters for readability.  The need for variable-name expansion is why the argument to `sed` is in double quotes, vs the stronger single quotes I use elsewhere, but in this case you could in fact use double quotes everywhere, or—with the `$'...'` syntax—single quotes everywhere (but another reason to use a variable like `$TAB` is that the `$'...'` syntax can be misleading).

Comment: I'd use `sed s,[^r]*refs/heads/,,` or `sed s,[^/]*/[^/]*/,,`.

Comment: @jthill: clever: `r` and `/` can't appear on the left and must appear on the right... I still like the `${TAB}refs/heads/` for clarity though. :-) (Not that it matters here, but long literal strings also speed up some matches via Boyer-Moore.)